# How to encrypt each part of a split file

Tags: java, file, encryption, file-io

I have a class which can split and merge a given file into multiple files but I would like to know how to encrypt each file when split and then decrypt when they are merged again.

Here's the class for file splitting and merging.

```
public void splitFile(File f) throws Exception {
    int partCounter = 1;

    int sizeOfFiles = (int) (f.length() / 3);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeOfFiles];

    String fileName = f.getName();
    String destFileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.')) + "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName);

    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis)) {

        int bytesAmount = 0;

        while ((bytesAmount = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {

            String filePartName = String.format("%s.%03d", destFileName, partCounter++);
            File newFile = new File("D:\\FileTest\\", filePartName);
            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFile)) {
                //I think this is how you encrypt each split part before it gets written to a file?
                out.write(FileEncrypt.encrypt(buffer, encKey), 0, bytesAmount);
            }
        }
        bos.close();
    }
}

public List<File> listOfFilesToMerge(File oneOfFiles) throws IOException, Exception {
    String tmpName = oneOfFiles.getName();
    String destFileName = tmpName.substring(0, tmpName.lastIndexOf('.'));
    File[] files = oneOfFiles.getParentFile().listFiles((File dir, String name) -> name.matches(destFileName + "[.]\\d+"));
    Arrays.sort(files);
    for (File f : files) {
        //And this is how to decrypt the files before it gets merged?
        FileEncrypt.decrypt(Files.readAllBytes(f.toPath()), encKey);
    }
    return Arrays.asList(files);
}

public void mergeFiles(List<File> files, File into) throws Exception {
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(into);
            BufferedOutputStream mergingStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fos)) {
        for (File f : files) {
            Files.copy(f.toPath(), mergingStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the encryption class.

```
public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] bytes, String key) throws Exception {
    byte[] iv = new byte[ivSize];
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    random.nextBytes(iv);
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    digest.update(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[keySize];
    System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(bytes);

    byte[] encryptedIVAndFile = new byte[ivSize + encrypted.length];
    System.arraycopy(iv, 0, encryptedIVAndFile, 0, ivSize);
    System.arraycopy(encrypted, 0, encryptedIVAndFile, ivSize, encrypted.length);

    return encryptedIVAndFile;
}

public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] encryptedIvFileBytes, String key) throws Exception {
    byte[] iv = new byte[ivSize];
    System.arraycopy(encryptedIvFileBytes, 0, iv, 0, iv.length);
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    int encryptedSize = encryptedIvFileBytes.length - ivSize;
    byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[encryptedSize];
    System.arraycopy(encryptedIvFileBytes, ivSize, encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedSize);

    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[keySize];
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    md.update(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    System.arraycopy(md.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

    Cipher cipherDecrypt = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipherDecrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipherDecrypt.doFinal(encryptedBytes);

    return decrypted;
}

public static String generateEncKey() {
    int strLen = 16;
    char[] chars = "abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789".toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new SecureRandom();
    for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
        char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
        sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

When I run the code, I get the error of - javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.

However, I can encrypt and decrypt a file without the splitting and merging.

So I would like to know what's wrong with the code that I can't encrypt each split part and then decrypt them.

Comment: `bis.read(buffer)` isn't guaranteed to read that many bytes, even if available.

Comment: If you split and then encrypt then it makes most sense to first decrypt and then merge. First merging is possible, but then you would need to know where the split happened because you can only decrypt the same parts that you encrypted in CBC mode.